# AjaxControlToolkit:TabContainer is not recognized in Umbraco 6.1.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, umbraco

i am using `Ajaxtoolkit 4.5` in my project but when i embed it in `Umbraco` and make a macro of it following error occur

```
System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): Unknown server tag 'AjaxControlToolkit:TabContainer'. 
---> System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): Unknown server tag 'AjaxControlToolkit:TabContainer'. 
---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Unknown server tag 'AjaxControlToolkit:TabContainer'.
 at System.Web.UI.TagPrefixTagNameToTypeMapper.System.Web.UI.ITagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs)
 at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType2(String tagName, IDictionary attribs, Boolean fAllowHtmlTags)
 at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs, Boolean fAllowHtmlTags)
 at System.Web.UI.RootBuilder.GetChildControlType(String tagName, IDictionary attribs)
 at System.Web.UI.ControlBuilder.CreateChildBuilder(String filter, String tagName, IDictionary attribs, TemplateParser parser, ControlBuilder parentBuilder, String id, Int32 line, VirtualPath virtualPath, Type& childType, Boolean defaultProperty)
 at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessBeginTag(Match match, String inputText)
 at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)
 at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex)
 at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)
 at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)
 at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)
 at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)
 at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseInternal() at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse()
 at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
 at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath)
 at umbraco.developer.assemblyBrowser.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

i tried googling alot but no help found. i am  still not conformed whether `Umbraco` supports `ajaxtoolkit 4.5` or not as it supports `ajaxtoolkit ver 3` in `Umbraco 4`
http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/adding-ajaxcontroltoolkit-v3-support-to-umbraco

**UPDATED**
emp_detail.aspx

```
<div>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<AjaxControlToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="1" Height="673px" Width="608px">
        <AjaxControlToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="Details">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style11">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Update</asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="268px" Visible="False">
                    <table style="width: 93%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">ID</td>
                            <td class="auto-style15">
                                <asp:Label ID="id_lab" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td class="auto-style1" rowspan="13">
                                <asp:Image ID="pic_img" runat="server" Height="122px" ImageUrl="/emp_img/pic-dummy.jpg" Style="margin-top: -75px" Width="107px" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">FIRST NAMEFIRST NAME</td>
                            <td class="auto-style15">
                                <asp:Label ID="fname_lab" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">LAST NAMELAST NAME</td>
                            <td class="auto-style15">
                                <asp:Label ID="lname_lab" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">EMAIL</td>
                            <td class="auto-style15">
                                <asp:Label ID="email_lab" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">ADDRESS</td>
                            <td class="auto-style15">
                                <asp:Label ID="addr_lab" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">JOB TYPEJOB TYPE</td>
                            <td class="auto-style15">
                                <asp:Label ID="jtype_lab" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">BAR CODEBAR CODE</td>
                            <td class="auto-style15">
                                <asp:Label ID="bcode_lab" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">STATUS</td>
                            <td class="auto-style15">
                                <asp:Label ID="status_lab" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">PER HOUR RATEPER HOUR RATE</td>
                            <td class="auto-style15">
                                <asp:Label ID="phr_lab" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">FIXED PRICEFIXED PRICE</td>
                            <td class="auto-style15">
                                <asp:Label ID="fprice_lab" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">CONTACT NUMCONTACT NUM</td>
                            <td class="auto-style15">
                                <asp:Label ID="cnum_lab" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">DATE OF JOININGDATE OF JOINING</td>
                            <td class="auto-style15">
                                <asp:Label ID="doj_lab" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">DATE OF LEAVINGDATE OF LEAVING</td>
                            <td class="auto-style15">
                                <asp:Label ID="dol_lab" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br />
                </asp:Panel>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Visible="False">
                    <h1>UpdateUpdate Profile Profile </h1>
                    <table style="width: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">FIRST NAMEFIRST NAME</td>
                            <td class="auto-style12">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="fname_tb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td rowspan="12" style="text-align: right">
                                <div id="img" style="margin-top: -50px;">
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="122px" ImageUrl="/emp_img/pic-dummy.jpg" Style="margin-top: -108px" Width="107px" /></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">LAST NAMELAST NAME</td>
                            <td class="auto-style12">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="lname_tb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">EMAIL</td>
                            <td class="auto-style12">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="email_tb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">ADDRESS</td>
                            <td class="auto-style12">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="addr_tb" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">JOB TYPEJOB TYPE</td>
                            <td class="auto-style12">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="jtype_ddl" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem>Select Job TypeSelect Job Type</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Full TimeFull Time</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Part TimePart Time</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Locum</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">BAR CODEBAR CODE</td>
                            <td class="auto-style12">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="bcode_tb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">STATUS</td>
                            <td class="auto-style12">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="status_ddl" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem>Select Status...Select Status...</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Active</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Inactive</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">PER HOUR RATEPER HOUR RATE</td>
                            <td class="auto-style12">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="phr_tb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">FIXED PRICEFIXED PRICE</td>
                            <td class="auto-style12">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="fprice_tb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">CONTACT NUMCONTACT NUM</td>
                            <td class="auto-style12">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="cnum_tb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">LEAVING DATELEAVING DATE</td>
                            <td class="auto-style12">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="end_date_tb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style5">&#160;</td>
                            <td class="auto-style12">
                                <asp:Button ID="upd_emp_btn" runat="server" OnClick="upd_emp_btn_Click" Text="Update" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:Panel>
                <br />
```

Select MonthJanuaryFebruaryMarchAprilMayJuneJulyAugustSeptemberOctoberNovemberDecember

```
                <table><tr><td style="background-color: #FF0000">&#160; &#160;&#160; &#160;</td><td>&#160; &#160;Absent</td><td style="background-color: green">&#160; &#160;</td><td>&#160; &#160;Present</td><td style="background-color: orange">&#160; &#160;</td><td>Sick LeaveSick Leave</td></tr></table><asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" OnVisibleMonthChanged="Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged" Visible="False"></asp:Calendar>

                <asp:Label ID="LabelAction" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" Visible="False"><ContentTemplate><br /><asp:Panel ID="details_panel" runat="server" Visible="false"><table style="width:100%;"><tr><td class="auto-style9">Employee Barcode</td><td class="auto-style7"><asp:Label ID="barcode_det_lab" runat="server"></asp:Label></td><td class="auto-style7"><asp:Label ID="leave_stat_lb" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>&#160;</td><td class="auto-style24">&#160;<strong>Leave</strong></td><td class="auto-style25"></td><td class="auto-style25"></td>
                                <td class="auto-style8">Time In&#160;</td><td class="auto-style7"><asp:Button ID="edit_btn0" runat="server" OnClick="edit_btn_Click" Text="Edit" /></td>
                                    <td class="auto-style7"></td></tr><tr><td class="auto-style9">Date</td><td class="auto-style7"><asp:Label ID="date_det_lab" runat="server"></asp:Label></td><td class="auto-style7">&#160;</td></tr><tr><td class="auto-style8">&#160;</td><td class="auto-style11">Time In</td><td class="auto-style11">Time Out</td></tr><tr><td class="auto-style8">&#160;</td><td class="auto-style7"><asp:PlaceHolder ID="tin_det_ph" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="auto-style7"><asp:PlaceHolder ID="tout_det_ph" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr></tr>
                                <tr></tr></table><br /></asp:Panel><asp:Panel ID="form_panel" runat="server" Visible="False"><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label><table style="width:100%;"><tr><td class="auto-style26">Employee Barcode</td><td class="auto-style28"><asp:Label ID="barcode_lab" runat="server"></asp:Label></td><td class="auto-style29">&#160;</td><td>&#160;</td></tr><tr><td class="auto-style26">Date</td><td class="auto-style28"><asp:Label ID="date_lab0" runat="server"></asp:Label></td><td class="auto-style29">&#160;</td><td>&#160;</td></tr><tr><td class="auto-style27">&#160;</td><td class="auto-style28"><b>Time In</b></td><td class="auto-style29"><b>Time Out</b></td><td>&#160;</td></tr><tr><td class="auto-style27">&#160;</td><td class="auto-style28"><asp:PlaceHolder ID="timein_placeholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="auto-style29"><asp:PlaceHolder ID="timeout_placeholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><asp:Button ID="add_rowbtn" runat="server" OnClick="add_rowbtn_Click" Text="Add Row" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr><td class="auto-style27"><strong>Leave</strong></td><td class="auto-style28"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_leave" runat="server"><asp:ListItem>Select Leave</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>Sick Leave</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>Casual Leave</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>Earned Leave</asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList></td><td class="auto-style29">&#160;</td><td>&#160;</td></tr><tr><td class="auto-style27">&#160;</td><td class="auto-style28"><asp:Button ID="update_btn" runat="server" OnClick="update_btn_Click" Text="Update" /></td>
                                    <td class="auto-style29">&#160;</td><td>&#160;</td></tr></table></asp:Panel><asp:Panel ID="timesheet_panel" runat="server"><asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"><Columns><asp:CommandField SelectText="Summary" ShowSelectButton="True" /></Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                            <br />Total Working this Month(Hours):<asp:Label ID="total" runat="server"></asp:Label></asp:Panel></ContentTemplate><ContentTemplate><asp:Button ID="add_atnd_btn" runat="server" OnClick="add_atnd_btn_Click" Text="Add Attendance" /><br /><asp:Label ID="err_lab0" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label><asp:Panel ID="add_atnd_panel" runat="server" Visible="False"><table style="width:100%;"><tr><td class="auto-style23">Barcode</td><td class="auto-style18"><asp:Label ID="bcode_addatnd_lab" runat="server"></asp:Label></td><td class="auto-style22">&#160;</td><td>&#160;</td></tr><tr><td class="auto-style19">Date</td><td class="auto-style20"><asp:Label ID="date_lab" runat="server"></asp:Label></td><td class="auto-style21"></td>
                                    <td>&#160;</td></tr><tr><td class="auto-style12">&#160;</td><td class="auto-style14">Time In</td><td class="auto-style22"><b>Time Out</b></td><td>&#160;</td></tr><tr><td class="auto-style12">&#160;</td><td class="auto-style18"><asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="auto-style22"><asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                        <td><asp:Button ID="add_row_btn" runat="server" OnClick="add_row_btn_Click" Text="Add Row" /></td>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr><td class="auto-style12">Leave</td><td class="auto-style18"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_holiday" runat="server"><asp:ListItem>Select Leave</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>Sick Leave</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>Casual Leave</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>Earned Leave</asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList></td><td class="auto-style22">&#160;</td><td>&#160;</td></tr><tr><td class="auto-style12">&#160;</td><td class="auto-style18"><asp:Button ID="insert_atnd_btn" runat="server" OnClick="insert_atnd_btn_Click" style="height: 26px" Text="ADD" /></td>
                                    <td class="auto-style22">&#160;</td><td>&#160;</td></tr></table></asp:Panel></ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel><br />
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Did you place the 4.5 version Ajaxcontroltoolkit in the bin folder or which version is placed there?

Comment: Can you also post the asp.net code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the namespace in your aspx-file

```
<%@ Import Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" %>
```